# How to put breakpoints inside a linked library in CLion?

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries, clion, dynamic-library

Is there a way to put a breakpoint inside a library linked in CLion? The library is compiled with debug symbols.
I can step inside of its code if I put a breakpoint in my code, but I would like to put a breakpoint directly inside of it.
The main problem is that I can't find an option or menu to "explore" its sources, even though they are clearly available to CLion and to the debugger.